# Sendgrid inbound for parse.com

Tags: json, parse-platform, multipartform-data, sendgrid

I want to use **sendgrid** webhook with **parse.com** cloud code. As per the sendgrid documentation for inbound "The request that will be sent to the HTTP endpoint will be encoded as **multipart/form-data**.". But parse.com does not supports multipart/form-data. So is there any option available to encode request in other format **(json / x-www-form-urlencoded)** ?

Comment: Does this get what you want?  https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-parse-api-example

Answer (score 1):

The SendGrid inbound parse webhook only supports `multipart/form-data` right now. Unfortunately I don't think there is a workaround that doesn't involve adding some service in the middle to transform the request.